# wxPython Plot overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, wxpython, figure

I am designing a GUI and got a problem with the configuration of my plots.
I won't post the whole script because it is hundreds of lines long.
 But I will show you my problem and the specific code segment:
[image: Extraction from my GUI]

So you see the ugly grey block from the polar plot. I don't know how to remove it, or make it as small as possible.

I need this to display multiple plot on one page.

Another minor problem is the `{0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0}` axis values from the polar plot.

Here comes my script extract, I hope you can help me.

```
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from mne.connectivity import spectral as sp
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

self.figure2 = Figure(figsize=(1,2))
self.axe2 = self.figure2.add_subplot(111)
self.z_plot = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure2)
self.axe2.set_axis_bgcolor('white')
self.axe2.set_title("Connectivity - Channel")
self.axe2.set_xlabel("Frequencs [Hz]")
self.axe2.set_ylabel("Value [  ]")
self.axe2.set_ylim(0, 1.05)
pylab.setp(self.axe2.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=8)
pylab.setp(self.axe2.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=8)
self.axe2.grid(True, color='gray')
# POLAR PLOT
self.figure3 = Figure(figsize=(1,1))
self.axe3 = self.figure3.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
self.P_plot = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure3)
self.P_plot.SetDimensions(860, 20, 500, 200)
self.axe3.set_axis_bgcolor('white')
```

Comment: The grey fill-in might be the `facecolor`. You may want to try `Figure(facecolor='white')` or `Figure(facecolor=[0,0,0,0])` (RGBA values).  Use `axe3.set_yticklabels([])` to get rid of the ticklabels.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The 'ticklabel problem' was solved long ago, but thanks anyway. Concerning your suggestion to the facecolor - I was aware of what it is and how I change the color.But changing it to white doesn't solve my problem. If it could be made invisible, that would be nice.

Comment: You may want to try `Figure(facecolor='none')` or use a RGBA tuple with the Alpha channel being `0` such as `[0,0,0,0]`.

Comment: thanks, it is what I was searching for. But unfortunately doesn't solve my problem. the plot face construct is the same size as always even transparent it overlaps other widgets.